# How to deny access to all subdirectories of current directory with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web-services, web, webserver

Say that I have the following directory structure:

```
/
/opt
/opt/lampp
/opt/lampp/htdocs/
/opt/lampp/htdocs/...
/opt/lampp/htdocs/.../project
```

And then within the `project/` directory, I have the following directory structure:

```
project/
project/.htaccess
project/index.php
project/dashboard.php
project/theme.css
project/...
project/subdir-1
project/subdir-1/...
project/subdir-2
project/subdir-2/...
project/subdir-3
project/subdir-3/...
```

What do I write in `project/.htaccess` to allow access to all files in the `project/` directory, but deny access to all the sub-directories (i.e. `subdir-*`) and all the files in each sub-directory?

Here is what I have so far:

.htaccess

```
# Deny access by default
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

# Allow access to all PHP/CSS files in current directory
<Files ~ "[^/]\{0,}\.(php|css)$">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

I'm basically trying to allow access to all PHP/CSS files, except for files with a `'/'` in the file name; however, the result is that I am unable to access anything. What would be the correct way to accomplish this?

Also, is there a cross-platform way to do this (i.e. So that it would work on both UNIX/Linux & Windows servers)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To deny access to all sub-directories of the /project folder, you can use the following mod-rewrite Rule in **project/.htaccess** :

```
RewriteEngine on

#if the request is for existent dirs, forbid the request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```

This returns a 403 error response if you request a directory that exists.

If you want to do this for both files/directories, you can use the following redirect

```
RedirectMatch 403 /project/.+/.*$
```

Comment: It seems that your solution is working for the most part (I no longer can access PHP files in sub-directories), but I am still able to download .txt files in sub-directories (e.g. `project/subdir-1/example.txt`).